# HTML async and defer

Tags: javascript, html, browser

The [documentation](https://bitsofco.de/async-vs-defer/) says that with `async` or `defer` attribute defined for the external script

> the file can be downloaded while the HTML document is still parsing

Does this mean that the browser fires extra thread when the parser reaches the `script` tag
? If so how does it relate to the statment

> JavaScript is single threaded

as stated on [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) site?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that the browser fires extra thread when the parser reaches the script tag?

That's an implementation detail.

> If so how does it relate to the statment
>
> > JavaScript is single threaded

It doesn't relate to it at all.

"Downloading an HTTP resource" and "Running a JavaScript program" are completely different things.